# Laravel getQueryLog show line query is executed

Tags: laravel

as title says I wonder if there is an way to get the `getQueryLog` function to show line of the query.

`var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())`

Comment: No, it does not do that out of the box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it with `getQueryLog()`, but you can listen to queries, generate a backtrace and finally extract line number:

```php
// routes.php
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query,$binding,$time,$connections){

  $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);

  foreach ($backtrace as $trace) {
    if(array_key_exists('file',$trace) && array_key_exists('line',$trace)){
      if( strpos($trace['file'],base_path().'/app') !== false ){
        var_dump(array(
          'query'    => $query
          ,'binding' => $binding
          ,'time'    => $time
          ,'connection' => $connections
          ,'file' => $trace['file']
          ,'line' => $trace['line']
        ));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```