# Detailed profiler/query analyzer for laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, profiling, profiler

I need a profiler package which shows running queries with which functions they are called in. I have already used a profiler package, debugbar and also looked at packalyst but I couldn't see this feature on any package. By the way, I am not sure even this is technically possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291639/laravel-getquerylog-show-line-query-is-executed/25297281), in your case just add `$trace['function']`