# Event::listen not catching laravel.query

Tags: events, laravel, laravel-4

I am pretty new to Laravel.  I am working on a REST api and was trying to look at the queries that were being generated from the models.  In my routes I have a route group set up.

```
Route::(["before" => "auth", function()
{
    Route::model("juror_subject", "JurorSubject");

    Route::get("juror_subject", [
        "as"    => "juror_subject/index"
        "uses"  => "JurorSubjectController@index"
    ]);
});
```

I wanted to see what query was actually being run.  I was watching a video by Jeffrey Way and he mentions that you can use Event::listen to see the query like so.

In routes:

```
Event::listen('laravel.query', function($sql){
    var_dump($sql);
});
```

However, when I load the url:

```
localhost:8080/api/juror_subject
```

It returns the json response and never seems to fire the laravel.query event.

Am I missing some element that is needed to get event listeners to work properly?  Is the type of routing I am using not firing a query?  If so, how would I go about dumping the queries using a route group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`laravel.query` is for Laravel 3 , use `illuminate.query` instead, also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291639/laravel-getquerylog-show-line-query-is-executed/25297281#25297281) for more details.
Moreover, call `DB::getQueryLog()` to get all ran queries ( no need for listener), or use [this](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) package which is pretty neat.